# How to make single instance of Activity with different data passed through Intents in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to make an Activity which should be created only once and then it should be updated based on certain values. First I tried to pass data through Intent but since I have made that activity as singleTask it do not get the new Intent object and uses the previous one.

What can be the way of passing the data to an Activity that is singleTask and needs to be updated on certain values?

Comment: yeah, it would help to know where is data coming from? other activity, other service  etc..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your activity is singleTask, you need to handle new intents in `onNewIntent` method

Comment: I tried with the intent passed in onNewIntent but that also didnt worked.

Answer (score 0):

What entity generates the new values? If it is a `Service` then your `Activity` can establish a communication channel, so the `Service` can notify the `Activity` with new data.

More info [here](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-CN/reference/android/app/Service.html#LocalServiceSample).